# JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting, arrays

What is the easiest way to insert a new object into an array of objects at the index position 0? No jQuery; MooTools okay; no `unshift()` because it's `undefined` in IE according to w3schools.

Comment: You'll probably still get responses saying "have you tried jquery?". :)

Comment: @JamesBrownIsDead, Have you tried jQuery? You really should. :P :P

Comment: @CMS is correct: `unshift` works on IE: http://jsbin.com/umolo

Comment: Yes, works from IE5 up, it even worked on Netscape Navigator 4 (as of 1999!!)

Comment: @o.k.w: I'll choose **MooTools** over jQuery every single day.

Comment: @CMS: IE 5.5 up. It's not in IE 5.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

W3CSchools is **really outdated**, the [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Unshift) method is part of the [ECMAScript 3rd Edition](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.4.4.13) standard which was approved and published as of December 1999.

There is *no reason* to avoid it nowadays, it is supported from IE 5.5 up.

It is safe to use it, even modern libraries like [jQuery](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.js) or [MooTools](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools.js) internally use it (you can check the source code :).

```
var array = [2,3];
array.unshift(1); // returns 3
// modifies array to [1, 2, 3]
```

This method returns the new array length, and inserts the element passed as argument at the first position of the array.

Comment: The questioner specifies no `unshift` because w3schools says it is unsupported in IE. As @CMS points out, that is out-of-date: w3schools doesn't even *track* IE<6 market share any more.

Comment: @CMS: I'd un-down-vote you after your clarification, but because you did it in the 5min grace window & therefore generated no revision history, it says I can't until you edit your answer (even though you did)... Sorry.

Comment: @CMS: almost edited your response myself to let me change my vote, but I figured that was a bit rude. :) Anyway, I've switched it to an up-vote now. Well deserved.

Answer (score 6):

Using [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method.

```
array.splice(index,howmany,element1,.....,elementX);
```

For inserting, 'howmany' = 0

Comment: `unshift` and `concat` are simpler than `splice` for what @JamesBrownIsDead wants to do.

Comment: @Dominic, very true indeed. I guess I'm just 'lazy' to remember different methods and just the more generic ones :P

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
var newItem = 3;
arr = [newItem].concat(arr);
```

Another option is to use `push` and reverse the indices - you can easily write an object that does that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `unshift()` if your intent is to modify the array, otherwise you can use `concat()` as Kobi suggested (which returns a new array and does not modify the involved arrays):

```
var arr = [1, 2], newItem = 3;
var newArr = [newItem].concat(arr); // newArr = [1, 2, 3], arr still = [1, 2]
```

See: [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)